# How can greenmail go wrong?

Tags: corporate-acquisition

I understand that,

> **Greenmail** is the practice of buying enough shares in a company to threaten a hostile takeover so that the target company will instead repurchase its shares at a premium. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/greenmail.asp

An example of this is,

> In 1979, Carl Icahn bought 9.9% of Saxon Industries stock for 7.21$ per share. Later, Saxon was forced to Repurchase its own share at 10.5 $ per share on February 13, 1980

My question is,

#### What can go wrong for the greenmailer? Is there an example of a failed greenmail attempt?

Comment: What can go wrong? You mean apart from "_Greenmail has largely been outlawed by most regulatory bodies._" from the page you cite?

Comment: @TripeHound I'm asking whether there are known cases where, after a greenmailer has purchased stocks, the stock price drops, presumably resulting in a failed greenmail attempt.